# Python difference between string formatting

Tags: python, string, lambda, formatting

long story short. Can someone explain it to me how is it that be, simple line of code can do the same as all of the for loop written by me?

```
def z1(code1, code2):
   parse = lambda x: int(x.replace('-', ''))
   code1, code2 = parse(code1), parse(code2)
   print(code1, code2)
   return ["%02d-%03d" % divmod(x, 1000) for x in range(code1, code2+1)] <---
```

here's my solution:

```
def z2(code1, code2):
  codes = []
  parse = lambda x: int(x.replace('-', ''))
  code1, code2= parse(code1), parse(code2)
  for x in range(code1, code2+1):
      x = str(x)
      a = x[0:2]
      b = x[2:6]
      c = a+"-"+b
      codes.append(f"{c}")
  return codes
```

Comment: Try `"%02d-%03d" % divmod(x, 1000)` and compare it with your logic for x = 312 and for x = 123456. Check especially what `divmod` does.

Comment: @luk2302 Ok, i do kinda understand, but would you be so kind, and explain it to me step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
["%02d-%03d" % divmod(x, 1000) for x in range(code1, code2+1)]
```

This is called list comprehension, allow writing more concise code than creating empty list and then append-ing in loop. Consider following example

```
squares = []
for i in range(5):
    squares.append(i**2)
```

is equivalent to

```
squares = [i**2 for i in range(5)]
```